# Should it be possible to address question closure votees

Tags: feature-request, comments, closed-questions, vote-to-close

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68841/bold-symbols-for-greek-letters), barbara said the following thing in her comment:

> (i addressed you with the comment since yours was the only one present, and only one "target" is recognized.)

As far as I understand it correctly, she wanted to address the people who voted for the closure, and happily one of them as well left a comment there (which is not always the case). Therefore I think it might be useful to be able to @-target the people who voted for the closure.

Comment: This is one for meta.SE